# Notification between classes using Observable

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a class with a list of users from a server.
Other classes can manipulate the list on the server e.g. call add or delete operation.
My Core-Class has a reference to the other classes which are manipulating the list on the server.

I would like to:

- Make a init call in Core-Class to get the list on the beginning
- The Core-Class will be notified by plugins each time the list was      manipulated on the server, so the Core-Class get the list from the server again.
- Notify other classes that the list was reloaded and forward the new list.

My structure

```
Core {

     users: [];

     plugin1: Plugin;
     plugin2: Plugin;

     //Get a new list of users from the server
     loadUsers() {
      userService.loadUsers.then(function (res) {
        this.users = res;
      })
     }

    }

    Plugin {

    //sends a request to the server to create a special user, 
    //depending on plugin implementation
    createUser();
    }
```

I'm only just starting of using rx. I understand the factory methods, hot vs cold observable and other basic stuff. But i can not imagine how to do it with rx in the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: "Notify other classes that the list was reloaded and forward the new list." Can't you just create an observable in Core and have the other classes subscribe to it? You could either make the observable an attribute on the class or add a subscribe method which would allow the collaborating classes to un/subscribe themselves.

Comment: Let say i create a observable to refresh the list. Other classes subscribe on it to get notify when a new list is there. How this observable can be triggered by some class that a refresh is required.

Comment: 1) The consumers shouldn't/wouldn't know the difference between a "refresh" and however else values are added to the list. 2) Add a refresh method to Core which fetches some data and then places it onto the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea of reactive implementation would be:

In your UserService add the following:

```
var loadSubject = new Subject();
var usersObservable = loadSubject.flatMap(
  Observable.fromPromise(<your http call that returns promise>)).share()

function loadUsers(){
  loadSubject.next(true);
}
```

Then each plugin that made changes will simply call:

```
userService.loadUsers();
```

Your Core, plugins, and other classes that would like to get updated will simply do:

```
loadService.usersObservable.subscribe(function(usersFreshValue){
  this.users = usersFreshValue;
})
```

Note that I used the '.share()' to avoid duplication of the data.

Possible improvements:

1. Instead of the loadUsers method, have each plugin call userService.loadSubject.next(true);
2. Use backpressure/buffering operators to avoid too frequent calls. For example debounce (CAUTION! when used incorrectly, might lead to starvation) or bufferWithTime + filter (to ensure you don't trigger on empty buffers)
3. Use behavioral/replay observables so that new subscribers will quickly get the latest value.

Comment: Is Share still required if I am using a Subject. Is subject not a hot/multicast observable?

Comment: I wish I knew :-)
I used the share to avoid duplication of data with each subscriber.